# PreparedStatement throws MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following Java code:

```
String query = "Select 1 from myTable where name = ? and age = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setInt(2, age);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Whenever I run the above code, it throws an exception on line 2 (where the PreparedStatement is declared):

```
Error 0221202: SQLException = com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND age = ?' at line 1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you established a connection with the variable `conn`?

Comment: What are the columns in `myTable`? Is there really one named `1`? If you want to select all columns but only one row, it's `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name=? AND age=? LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Good catch about the column being named "1." There is no column named "1" but rather a column named birthday. I've now changed my query to read "Select birthday from myTable where name = ? and age = ?" but the same error message persists. There are columns named "name" and "age" with appropriate data types (string and int).

Comment: After changing from "select 1" to "select birthday", I noticed that the error moved down to my executeQuery() statement. My actual example was more complicated and it loops over the PreparedStatement without calling clearParameters. So this problem is now fixed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
String query = "Select 1 from myTable where `name` = ? and age = ?";
```

or

```
String query = "Select count(*) from myTable where `name` = ? and age = ?";
```

---

anyway your code is working perfectly for me;
Are you sure there are no special characters in your String?
What are the MySQL and driver version being used?
Is this the correct code?

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the `PreparedStatement` class only supports SQL "IN" parameterized lists. Looks like you want to change it to using the [`prepareCall`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29) function instead:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
```

And `CallableStatement` extends `PreparedStatement` so it's really easy to make the change.

Comment: Please don't retaliate when people downvote.  Instead, try to improve your answer based on what information you have available, such as high-rated answers.